# Convert Country Code Phone Prefix to ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 format

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I need the ability to map between numeric country code (phone prefix) and  [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2)

```
1   -> 'US'
972 -> 'IL'
```

And so on.

I'm using [google phone numbers lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-libphonenumber), they work with  ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 format, but when fetching phones from let's say iPhone, I get the numeric values.

Any idea? trying to avoid creating the map myself.

Comment: Could you show us some code and examples of numbers that aren't working?

Comment: I don't have now anything working... This question is aiming for a public mapping